# GPIO.output() works, GPIO.PWM() does not

Tags: gpio, python, led

I'm working on a project with a RGB LED which has to indicate what the status of the internet connection is. It is running as a service. I'm focused on two files, one to check if there is an internet connection and one for controlling the LED.

The following code is where we check if there is an internet connection and trying to call the LED function:

```
import logging

from status_server import status_led

def testInternetConnection():
    logging.info("Testing the internet connection...")

    while True:
        try:
            r = requests.get(https://google.com)

            # HTTP 200 OK
            if r.status_code == 200:
                logging.info("Internet connection is OK!")
                status_led.turn_green()
                break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            logging.warning("Re-trying the internet connection....")
            status_led.turn_red()
            time.sleep(10)
```

It is working fine with the following code in the LED file:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class _RGBLed:
    def __init__(self, red_pin, green_pin, blue_pin):
        self.RED_PIN = red_pin
        self.GREEN_PIN = green_pin

    self.init_pins()

    def init_pins(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.RED_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(self.GREEN_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

    def turn_red(self)
        GPIO.output(self.RED_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)

    def turn_green(self):
        GPIO.output(self.GREEN_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)


_rgb_led = _RGBLed(red_pin=26, green_pin=19)


def turn_red():
    _rgb_led.turn_red()


def turn_green():
    _rgb_led.turn_green()
```

The LED is quite bright so I wanted to add `PWM` to control the LED and lower the duty cycle. I've tested a bit with `PWM` in the Python live environment and that wasn't that hard. I've changed the `turn_green` and `turn_red` functions with the following:

```
def turn_green():
    turn_green_on = GPIO.PWM(GREEN_PIN, 100)
    turn_green_on.start(20)

def turn_red():
    turn_red_led_on = GPIO.PWM(RED_PIN, 100)
    turn_red_led_on.start(20)
```

I'm calling those functions from another 
When I do this it says `name GREEN_PIN is not defined`. When I change `GREEN_PIN` to 19 it doesn't give me warnings anymore, but the LED does nothing too. I've checked if the function is called by adding a log statement so that's not the problem either.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: We can't tell as the question has inconsistent code snippets.  Could you post the complete code you are actually trying to use?

Comment: I've added some code, hope this makes more sense

Comment: Not really.  You have three definitions of turn_red and three of turn_green.  Some may be in the _RBGLed class but we can't tell because the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should be more clear now.

Comment: GREEN_PIN/RED_PIN are class variables only available within the class.  You have setmode() within the class.  Are you still calling the class at all?  Otherwise where are you calling setmode()?

Comment: Have joan's questions set you on the right track or is your problem still unsolved?

Comment: Was out for a couple of days but the problem is still unsolved. The LED file is called status_led.py and is called at `status_led.turn_green()` and `status_led.turn_red()`. This works perfectly fine when I just use the `GPIO.output(self.GREEN_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)` way to do it, but not when I use the PWM way to do it. I'm not very experienced, so I think it is a small thing I'm not seeing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Per PWM's Wiki: (https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/PWM/)

> *Note that PWM will also stop if the instance variable 'p' goes out of
>   scope.*

Your variables are going out of scope (the scope of the method) as soon as you call it, to make them "permanent" basically in your class make both `turn_green_on` and `turn_red_led_on` instance variables, most likely defined in your class constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._turn_green_on = None
    self._turn_red_led_on = None
    ...
```

And in your class' method:

```
def turn_green():
   self._turn_green_on = GPIO.PWM(GREEN_PIN, 0.5)
   self._turn_green_on.start(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your PWM-frequency is 100Hz and your duty cycle is 20%. This would mean, that your LED is on for 1s/100*0.2 = 2ms and off for about 1s/100*0.8 = 8ms (and so on). Are you sure you can see that? Maybe you should start with

```
def turn_green():
   turn_green_on = GPIO.PWM(GREEN_PIN, 0.5)
   turn_green_on.start(20)
```

to be sure to be able to visually detect a working setup.

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't do anything with the led. I've tried this in the Python live environment and that does give me a blinking green LED, so it is something in the bigger code.